# Add concatenated string with separator using VBA

Tags: vba, function, concatenation

I'm trying various codes found in this forum to concatenate a varying range every time the program is being run.

### I need to set the value in Range("B1") the concatenated values for a specific range (e.g. A5 to last row with value in col A). Also concatenated values should be separated by ", " (that's a comma and a space).

Reason why not duplicate:
I need the value to be shown in Range("B1") but I have to input the "Join" function using vba alone and would not require me to type the UDF in B1.

Range in A has varying last row no. depending on the record needed to be concatenated. Existing question defines exact no. of row while I need a code that is flexible.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the code you have tried and the kind of trouble you faced?

Comment: I was trying to use UDF but it's not working.

`Function Join(rng As Range, delimiter As String) As String
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In rng
    Join = Join & cell.Text & delimiter
Next cell
Join = Left(Join, Len(Join) - Len(delimiter))
End Function`

Comment: If you have office 365 Excel you can use textjoin: textjoin (",",true,A:A)

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating with & (+ would work as well, but could sometimes cause problems).

```
for each cell in range
    result = result & cell.value & ", "
next cell
' get rid of the last ", "
result = left(result, len(result)-2)
```

Comment: Should I use this as UDF?

Answer (score 0):

edited after OP's clarifications

you can use:

```
Range("B1").value = Join(Application.Transpose(Rng1), ", ")
```

and you may also want to adopt the following refactoring of your code:

```
Sub New_Segment()
    Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, c As Range

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Mapping")
        Set Rng2 = .Range("A1:D" & .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row)
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Segment Generator")
        Set Rng1 = .Range("A5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        For Each c In Rng1
            c.Offset(, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(c, Rng2, 4, False)
        Next
        .Range("B1").value = Join(Application.Transpose(Rng1), ", ")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: But how should I add it in the existing Sub so that Range("B1") will have the joined value of available records in Col A separated by ", "?

Comment: show the "existing sub"

Comment: `Sub New_Segment()

Dim Rng1, Rng2, Rng3, c, i As Range
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Segment Generator").Activate

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Segment Generator")
Set Rng2 = Worksheets("Mapping").Range("A1:D" & ws2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)

On Error Resume Next

tbl1_r = ws1.Range("B5").Row
tbl1_c = ws1.Range("B5").Column

For Each i In Rng1
    ws1.Cells(tbl1_r, tbl1_c) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(i, Rng2, 4, False)
    tbl1_r = tbl1_r + 1
Next i
    
End Sub`

Comment: I need to add the formula or concatenated values in Range("B1") to complete the code.

Comment: where is the concatenated values to be inserted in your code? BTW your code is missing some pieces: 1) where is `ws2` defined? 2) where is `Rng1` defined?

Comment: Due to text count limitations, I wasn't able to include all definition to set delimiters.
1. Concatenated values should be inserted before "End Sub"
2. ws2 refers to another sheet where I will lookup the values
3. Rng1 is defined as `Set Rng1 = Worksheets("Segment Generator").Range("A5:A" & ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)`
Rng1 is basically the Array I need to concatenate.

Comment: see edited answer where I also propose you e refactoring of your code with the main goal to avoid `Select`/`Selection`/`Activate`/`ActiveXXX` pattern and work with fully qualified range references

Comment: @atserk, did you get through it?